# Relational database vs. Dimensional database

Tags: ssas

I was reading this [MS TechNet SSAS article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166713.aspx) and got a question:

In the beginning of Current Analysis Environment, the article says:

> ...consolidates this information into the AdventureWorksDW2012 relational data warehouse. However, the relational data warehouse presents the following challenges...

And in the Solution section, it says:

> The data warehouse team determined that the AdventureWorksDW2012 database is a well-designed dimensional database with conformed dimensions and surrogate keys.

I was wondering how this AdventureWorksDW2012 is both relational and dimensional at the same time. I thought those two terms are kind of mutual exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is a terminology thing. In OLAP systems, measures and "dimensions" are how you model data in what is called a "data warehouse".You model measures and dimensions with a relational database, the relationships are typically from a "fact" table to various "dimension" tables, so a dimensional database is a concept implemented in a relational database (in this case). The Star and Snowflake schemas are typical, then these schemas can be the basis for cubes, and cubes are multidimensional structures. It's a lot of buzzwords, but really data warehouses are relational databases that store dimensional data. BTW, there are other ways to implement data warehouses and multidimensional data NOT in a relational database, so don't think what I am saying is the only way.

Comment: Thanks! Now my understanding is - it's not really the "relational" feature that "presents the challenges". It's probably how the "reports" was constructed using traditional SQL that causes those challenges. The confusing part of this article is that it made it sound like the AdventureWorksDW2012 database was initially built without considering the dimensional feature. Actually it already has all the fact and dim tables.